# Issues with OAuth2 and angular-auth2-oidc Library - PKCE Code Flow

Tags: javascript, angular, oauth-2.0, angular-oauth2-oidc

I'm new in OAuth2 and the [angular-auth2-oidc](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc) library so bear with me if i make some newbie mistakes.

**WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE:** A user will click on the login link in the home page, he will be sent to the provider's site to login and then redirect back to the home page with token.

**RESULTS SO FAR:** A user is sent to the provider's site to login and sent back to my site's home page successfuly but I don't get any token.
I output some data in the console in the `ngOnit()` and they are all null, undefined or false.

Inside the `ngOnit()` function also i output some events and the events I get in de console is `token_refresh_error`. I don't do any token refresh in my code explicitely but i still get this error.

Under the **Error** sub-heading of this post I have added screenshots about the errors.

**Here are my config and implementation:**

**Here is the openid configuration of the my OAuth2 provider:**

```
authorization_endpoint                  "https://DOMAIN_PROVIDER/op/v1/auth"
code_challenge_methods_supported    
    0                                   "plain"
    1                                   "S256"
end_session_endpoint                    "https://DOMAIN_PROVIDER/op/v1/logout"
grant_types_supported   
    0                                    "authorization_code"
id_token_signing_alg_values_supported   
    0                                    "RS256"
issuer                                   "https://DOMAIN_PROVIDER/op"
jwks_uri                                 "https://DOMAIN_PROVIDER/op/v1/keys"
response_modes_supported    
    0                                    "query"
    1                                    "fragment"
    2                                    "form_post"
response_types_supported    
    0                                    "code"
scopes_supported    
    0                                    "openid"
subject_types_supported 
    0                                    "public"
token_endpoint                           "https://DOMAIN_PROVIDER/op/v1/token"
token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported   
    0                                    "client_secret_basic"
    1                                    "client_secret_post"
userinfo_endpoint                        "https://DOMAIN_PROVIDER/op/v1/userinfo"
```

**Here is my implementation:**

**// Home page component**

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  private oAuthConfig: AuthConfig;

  constructor(private oAuthService: OAuthService) { }

   ngOnInit() {

     // IN THIS METHOD I'M OUTPUTTING ALOT OF STUFF TO THE CONSOLE TO SEE IF IT IS WORKING

      if (!this.oAuthService.getAccessToken()) {
         this.initOAuthConfig();
         console.log('__________ACCESS-TOKEN IS NOT SET___________');
      } else {
         console.log('___ACCESS-TOKEN IS SET:', this.oAuthService.getAccessToken());
      }

      console.log('_____GRANTED-SCOPE:', this.oAuthService.getGrantedScopes());
      console.log('______IDENTITY-CLAIMS:', this.oAuthService.getIdentityClaims());
      console.log('______HAS-ACCESS-TOKEN?:', this.oAuthService.hasValidAccessToken());
      console.log('_____HAS-ACCESS-TOKEN?:', this.oAuthService.hasValidIdToken());
      
    // HERE I'M OUTPUTTNG THE EVENTS TO SEE WHAT IS GOING ON
    this.oAuthService.events.subscribe((e: OAuthErrorEvent) => {
      if (e.type === 'token_received') {
        this.logger.log('____________TOKEN RECEIVED');
      }
      this.logger.log('______====================EVENT-TYPE:', e.type);
      this.logger.log('______====================EVENT-REASON:', e.reason);
      this.logger.log('______====================EVENT-PARAMS:', e.params);
    });

  
    if (this.oAuthService.hasValidAccessToken()) {
      this.oAuthService.loadUserProfile().then((t) => {
        console.log('----USER-PROFILE:', t);
      });
    } else {
      this.logger.log('----HAS VALID ACCESS TOKEN');
    }

   }

  
   
   private initOAuthConfig(): void {
    this.oAuthConfig = {
      redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/login/oauth2/myapp',
      postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin + '/logout',
      clientId: 'CLIENT-ID',
      scope: 'openid, rrn, profile',
      oidc: true,
      issuer: 'https://DOMAIN_PROVIDER/op',
      responseType: 'code',
      showDebugInformation: true,
      tokenEndpoint: 'DOMAIN_PROVIDER/op/v1/token',
      jwks: {'keys': ['DOMAIN_PROVIDER/op/v1/keys']}
    };

    this.oAuthService.setStorage(sessionStorage);
    this.oAuthService.configure(this.oAuthConfig);
    this.oAuthService.loadDiscoveryDocumentAndTryLogin();

}
```

**// The class that contains the login function**

```
export class HeaderComponent {

    
   constructor(private oAuthService: OAuthService) { }


    public login() {
     this.oAuthService.initCodeFlow();
    }

    public logout() {
      this.oAuthService.logOut();
    }

}



// The html of the header component which contains the login link

    <a (click)="login()" title="Login">
       Login
    </a>
```

**// Errors / Screenshots of errors**

The following are errors in the console when a user is redirected back to the home page

**1)** In this screenshot the values are null, false or undefined except when discovery document is loaded:

[image]

**2)** In the following screenshot you will see that one of the **EVENT-TYPE** is `token_refresh_error`. and the **EVENT-REASON** is `BAD REQUEST`. It is trying to make a request to `https//DOMAIN_PROVIDER/op/v1/token` and is failing though in de **initOAuthConfig()** method I have added the `tokenEndPoint` attribute.
You can also see that the error is `error: "invalid_grant"`.
The second line of the screenshot says **Error getting token**

I added `jwks: {'keys': ['https://DOMAIN_PROVIDER/op/v1/keys']}` to **initOAuthConfig()** thinking that it will solve the problem but it didn't.

[image]

**// Application tab of the console: Session storage**

From the application tab of the console I can see that there are some key-value pairs of data in the session-storage (there is no data in the localstorage) See the next screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I would aim to implement your solution in 2 stages:

- First understand the OAuth and Open Id Connect design patterns - see my simple TypeScript code sample
- Think about the best way to translate the sample to Angular, which I'm sure you can do easily enough

**CONFIGURATION FILE**

I like to express OAuth settings via JSON configuration - see [this file](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1/blob/master/spa/spa.config.json). You can update the file to match your configuration, run my sample, then hopefully you will see a token coming back.

**API CLIENT RESPONSIBILITY**

When the UI calls the API it must first get an access token, and the UI must also handle expired / 401 responses - see [this class](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1/blob/master/spa/src/api/client/apiClient.ts).

**OAUTH CLIENT RESPONSIBILITY**

The API client calls [this class](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/authenticator.ts) to get a token, which uses the OIDC Client library to manage redirects, responses and returning tokens.

**EXPLANATORY BLOG POST**

See also these write ups, which I've aimed to keep visual and easy to read:

- [Overview](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/24/basicspa-overview/)
- [OAuth Messages](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/26/basicspa-oauthworkflow/)
- [Coding Key Points](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/28/basicspa-codingkeypoints/)